# Jquery Select2 : Not able to set outside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a variable outside, and i want to set the variable to some value when the select2 is changed.

I am unable to do it.

```
var variable = "unset"

$("#periods-selectYear").select2({
            }).on("change", function(e) {
               var variable = "set"
            });
```

Any help will be great.

I don't want to use window.variable for accessing the variable outside.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you're using 'var' again, that's creating a new instance

it should be

```
var variable = "unset";
$("#periods-selectYear").select2({
}).on("change", function(e) {
    variable = "set";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8r6t63s/